# Exact route matching with query strings in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have one route as `/addresses` which returns all the addresses of the user.

I need to create another API which accepts filters `latitude` and `longitude`.

Anyone can pass those filter in the same route as `/addresses?lat=23.23&lng=-70.22`.

In this case I have to modified my previous controller method to check for the filters.

*Is it possible in express?* I could create a different route with exact match with query strings.

Like it's done with query params `/addresses/:addressId`.

So for this it will hit different controller:

```
/addresses    AddressController.getAllAddresses()
/addresses?lat=:lat&lng=:lng   AddressController.getAddressByLatLngFilter()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the first route handler you can check for the presence of query params, and if present, redirect to another route handler:

```
app.get('/addresses', geo.addresses )
```

And define the route handlers in a way that one can defer to another:

```
var this_module = module.exports =  {

 "addresses":  function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.lat && req.query.lng) {
      return this_module.addresses_by_loc(req,res,next);
    }
    // handle one way...
  },

 "addresses_by_loc": function(req, res, next) {
    // handle another
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks a better approach, but still, is it possible what I have mentioned above?

Comment: @Magnetaar I don't think there's a way to do that using the Express route patterns, as the part before the `?` defines the route and the part after is the query parameters.  Still it's just syntactic sugar whether you express the conditional routing either in Express's router pattern matching, or explicitly within your own code. That said SO is full of posts where an accepted answer says "X isn't possible" and a later answer shows it is.